# Summing column if values in another column fit criteria [R]

Tags: r

I am currently trying, with no avail, to find a way to sum up one column of my data frame (Balance) for each month (M1, M2 etc.) - if the amount in each month is above a certain value (less than 1 for example).

I have tried loops and the lapply formula, but get various errors, as can be seen below. Unfortunately I cannot do this manually as the df is too large.

This is the kind of thing I have tried so far and an example df:

```
df["<=1M",] <- for (i in 1:ncol(df)){for (j in 1:nrow(df)){sum(df$Balance[which(df[i,j]<=1)]}}

df["<=1M",] <- lapply(df, function(i) sum(df$Balance[cumulative[i,1:ncol(df)] <= 1]))

M1  M2  M3  M4  M5  Balance
0   0   0   1   2   100
1   2   2   3   3   200
0   0   0   0   0   200
1   1   1   1   1   200
1   2   3   4   5   250
```

Any tips or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: so what would be the output of your given example?

Comment: Apologies. This is the output for the example: <=1M 950 500 500 500 400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try

```
as.vector(sapply(df[1:5], function(x) sum(df$Balance[x <=1])))
#[1] 950 500 500 500 400
```

---

Or using `vectorized` approach

```
colSums(df$Balance*(df[1:5] <=1))
# M1  M2  M3  M4  M5 
#950 500 500 500 400
```